# Incompatible pointer types passing retainable parameter of type 'float [2]'to a CF function expecting 'const CGFloat *' (aka 'const double *') type

Tags: ios, xcode, arm64

I'm getting this error,I compiled under arm64 appear this mistake:

```
CGContextSetLineDash(line, 0, lengths, 1);  //画虚线
```

How do I solve this?

```
- (id)initDashLineWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView1.frame.size);   //开始画线
    [imageView1.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView1.frame.size.width, imageView1.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);  //设置线条终点形状


    float lengths[] = {4,5};
    CGContextRef line = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIColor *coloreline = [UIColor colorWithRed:156/255.0 green:156/255.0 blue:156/255.0 alpha:1];//r(156, 156, 156, 1);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(line, coloreline.CGColor);

    CGContextSetLineDash(line, 0, lengths, 1);  //画虚线
    CGContextMoveToPoint(line, 0.0, 5.0);    //开始画线
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(line, 310.0, 5.0);
    CGContextStrokePath(line);

    imageView1.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    return imageView1;
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On 64-bit architectures (like arm64), `CGFloat` is defined as `double` and therefore a
8-byte floating point number, whereas `float` is a 4-byte floating point number. Therefore you cannot pass a `float[]` array
to a function expecting a `CGFloat[]` array.

Changing your array to

```
CGFloat lengths[] = {4,5};
```

should solve the problem.